# Obout Grid control on a tab control

Tags: grid, controls, obout

I'm using an Obout Grid inside an Obout tab control. I'm using Iframes to load the grid inside the tab. If i open a tab and click onto another tab before the data grid finishes loading it doesn't show the data in the grid. But if i let it load it without clicking away, it shows the data just fine. I'm binding the control correctly as it load ok if i allow for the tab to completely load the data loads ok. I was wondering if anybody here had seen this issue. I'm using the control in ASP.NET 4.0 and C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that in the obout css for the grid i needed to set the height and overflow-y="auto". This fixed my problem.